# Redirects - htcaccess or cloudflare?

Tags: wordpress

I'm having issues with a client site.

The issue is that there seems to be a redirect on a URL which doesn't exist/has no content:

[www.henparty-houses.com/liverpool](http://www.henparty-houses.com/liverpool)

Yet if we changed the end URL to another with no content / does not exist we get the correct page load (i.e. page doesn't exist).

[www.henparty-houses.com/leeds](http://www.henparty-houses.com/leeds)

===

There seems to be some sort of redirect on the /liverpool URL.

The issue is when a page is create, ending with the URL /liverpool - it is not possible to use this URL as wordpress think's it's already in use / taken.

I might be missing something obvious or some sort of error, but I need to somehow clear the /liverpool URL so content can be used, and ensure when a page with content is created using /liverpool there is no redirect!

Can someone please help?

---- when checking this redirect, here is the output. I've checked clourflare and can't see any redirects setup:

Results:
[www.henparty-houses.com/liverpool](http://www.henparty-houses.com/liverpool)

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 10:08:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d440b3cca7954a48bdc3f84b50e73ea7a1601028515; expires=Sun, 25-Oct-20 10:08:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.henparty-houses.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Location: https://www.henparty-houses.com/liverpool
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 10:08:36 GMT
Host-Header: b7440e60b07ee7b8044761568fab26e8
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 05665580120000ed6fcaa52200000001
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5d83f1e01a84ed6f-SJC

https://www.henparty-houses.com/liverpool

HTTP/2 302
date: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 10:08:39 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=d974040f170c5090b9a4e61af9590d1b61601028518; expires=Sun, 25-Oct-20 10:08:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.henparty-houses.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
x-cache-enabled: True
p3p: CP="ALL DSP NID CURa ADMa DEVa HISa OTPa OUR NOR NAV DEM"
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://www.henparty-houses.com
cache-control: max-age=0
expires: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 10:08:38 GMT
host-header: b7440e60b07ee7b8044761568fab26e8
x-proxy-cache: MISS
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 05665588c800009623ca33e200000001
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 5d83f1ee09ee9623-SJC

https://www.henparty-houses.com

HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 10:08:41 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=d63a3cce54fa1ecc1e3d8bbf7c7415b8d1601028519; expires=Sun, 25-Oct-20 10:08:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.henparty-houses.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
x-cache-enabled: True
p3p: CP="ALL DSP NID CURa ADMa DEVa HISa OTPa OUR NOR NAV DEM"
link: ; rel="https://api.w.org/", ; rel="alternate"; type="application/json", ; rel=shortlink
vary: Accept-Encoding
cache-control: max-age=0
expires: Fri, 25 Sep 2020 10:08:40 GMT
host-header: b7440e60b07ee7b8044761568fab26e8
x-proxy-cache: MISS
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 0566558f4e0000930a5d2f8200000001
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 5d83f1f87ede930a-SJC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find the answer looking in your `.htaccess` files. As you can see from the headers, the redirect is being issued by WordPress itself.

```
x-redirect-by: WordPress
```

If you go to your WordPress installation directory, you can use the following command to find the function that sets this header.

```
grep --line-number --with-filename --fixed-strings -i -R 'x-redirect-by' .
```

The result is pretty short:

```
./wp-includes/pluggable.php:1284:                * Filters the X-Redirect-By header.
./wp-includes/pluggable.php:1296:                       header( "X-Redirect-By: $x_redirect_by" );
```

Unsurprisingly, the function that sets this header is called `wp_redirect`.

In short, the problem is probably not the server configuration. What I think is happening is that one of your pages' slug is set to `liverpool`.

Normally, when WordPress receives a request for a page that doesn't exist (triggering a `404` error), it first attempts to redirect the request to a "canonical" URL (see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101585/wheres-the-redirect-happening)). These canonical URLs are called "slugs".

If one of your existing pages has a slug set to `liverpool`, this would trigger the URL canonicalization process. It's therefore possible that maybe that page is set to hidden, or is manually redirecting the user because it requires the user to be logged in, or a myriad of other things. Either way, a manual redirect is the reason for the `302` redirect. The best way to find out what exactly is going on is to find the page with that particular slug.

The reason I'm inclined to believe the page exists right now is that a `302` means `Found`. If a page had previously used a slug of `liverpool` and then changed it, the proper response would have been a `301 Moved Permanently` with a redirect to the current version of the page. My thinking is that a page exists with a slug of liverpool that is purposefully redirecting the client to the main page. The solution, therefore, is most likely tracking that one page down.

You can speed this process up significantly by accessing the database directly, rather than via the user interface. The `wp_posts` table contains most of the page content (see [the WordPress documentation](https://wp-staging.com/docs/the-wordpress-database-structure/#wp_posts_wp_postmeta) for a more in-depth explanation), and the `wp_postmeta` table contains post metadata.

I would start by running a query like this (I'm assuming you're using MariaDB or MySQL, but a Postgres or whatever query would be analogous, if not identical).

```
SELECT `wp_posts`.`post_name` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_name` LIKE '%liverpool%';
```

This query should get you close. If you can't find anything there, you might want to check the `wp_postmeta` table. Depending on how large the site's database is, it might actually be easier to just go page by page in the UI and check by hand, since a lot of entries are either serialized objects, HTML, or just generally hard to visually parse.

```
SELECT `wp_postmeta`.* FROM `wp_postmeta`;
```

You can use another `LIKE` clause here, obviously, which might be helpful to try first, before running this one. Keep in mind it might take a while to run though since it has to filter the results based on a wildcard match, so it might be helpful to run this basic query first so you have all the results, then the specific query on another console, so you can try to go through the output while the other query executes. I'm not sure how fast the hardware you're on is, but I speak from personal experience lol.

I would start by running the following query on any tables you're working with so you can get a handle of the table structure.

```
DESCRIBE `wp_postmeta`;
DESCRIBE `wp_posts`;
```

You can also do `SHOW TABLES` to actually see all of the tables in the database you're working with.

You should also take a look at [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183598/removing-the-redirect-after-changing-a-pages-slug). In particular, note where it says you can disable redirects by adding the `remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect');`. I'm not personally familiar with that functionality, but if you look at the `wp_redirect` function definition (`$WORDPRESS_INSTALL_DIR/wp-includes/pluggable.php`, line 1246), you can see the function applies filters elsewhere defined.

Note also that the function specifically checks to make sure the status code is between `300` and `399`, meaning ***something*** is changing the status code from `404` to `302`.

Here is the function definition, for your convenience and edification.

```
/**
 * Redirects to another page.
 *
 * Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be
 * followed by a call to `exit;`:
 *
 *     wp_redirect( $url );
 *     exit;
 *
 * Exiting can also be selectively manipulated by using wp_redirect() as a conditional
 * in conjunction with the {@see 'wp_redirect'} and {@see 'wp_redirect_location'} filters:
 *
 *     if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {
 *         exit;
 *     }
 *
 * @since 1.5.1
 * @since 5.1.0 The `$x_redirect_by` parameter was added.
 * @since 5.4.0 On invalid status codes, wp_die() is called.
 *
 * @global bool $is_IIS
 *
 * @param string $location      The path or URL to redirect to.
 * @param int    $status        Optional. HTTP response status code to use. Default '302' (Moved Temporarily).
 * @param string $x_redirect_by Optional. The application doing the redirect. Default 'WordPress'.
 * @return bool False if the redirect was cancelled, true otherwise.
 */
function wp_redirect( $location, $status = 302, $x_redirect_by = 'WordPress' ) {
    global $is_IIS;

    /**
     * Filters the redirect location.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string $location The path or URL to redirect to.
     * @param int    $status   The HTTP response status code to use.
     */
    $location = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect', $location, $status );

    /**
     * Filters the redirect HTTP response status code to use.
     *
     * @since 2.3.0
     *
     * @param int    $status   The HTTP response status code to use.
     * @param string $location The path or URL to redirect to.
     */
    $status = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect_status', $status, $location );

    if ( ! $location ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( $status < 300 || 399 < $status ) {
        wp_die( __( 'HTTP redirect status code must be a redirection code, 3xx.' ) );
    }

    $location = wp_sanitize_redirect( $location );

    if ( ! $is_IIS && 'cgi-fcgi' !== PHP_SAPI ) {
        status_header( $status ); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups.
    }

    /**
     * Filters the X-Redirect-By header.
     *
     * Allows applications to identify themselves when they're doing a redirect.
     *
     * @since 5.1.0
     *
     * @param string $x_redirect_by The application doing the redirect.
     * @param int    $status        Status code to use.
     * @param string $location      The path to redirect to.
     */
    $x_redirect_by = apply_filters( 'x_redirect_by', $x_redirect_by, $status, $location );
    if ( is_string( $x_redirect_by ) ) {
        header( "X-Redirect-By: $x_redirect_by" );
    }

    header( "Location: $location", true, $status );

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With this I managed to solve it - it did exist but wasn't showing on the Wordpress Admin Panel. So using the database to location the liverpool in the database in wp_posts and then deleting the entry solved it. Many thanks for the detail answer

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad it helped